# how to compute class weight for multi labels (imbalance data)?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, svm, conv-neural-network

[This answer](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-implement-cost-sensitive-learning-in-TensorFlow-to-penalize-for-misclassification-on-minority-classes-data-has-a-class-imbalance-problem) explains how can we use the class weights to penalize misclassification in the Tensorflow. The dataset that I used is more complicated so I still have problem to use class weights.

There are **7-classes** {c0, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6}

The number of samples of each class are:

> **all samples**  = 98070
>   **c0**      = 1607
>
> **c1**      = 5292
>
> **c2**      = 4322
>
> **c3**      = 3322
>
> **c4**    = 6629
>
> **c5**      = 7507
>
> **c6**      = 69391

The **perecntages** of these classes respectively:
 [ 1.6%, 5.4%, 4.4%, 3.4%, 6.7%, 7.6%, 71% ]

The **Tensorflow model** classified every test samples as  **c6** without using the class weights.
I want to product the logits with **class weight** to solve this problem. However, since that I should down-weight the loss for the majority classes and up-weight the loss for the minority classes, ***I do not have any idea how can I use the class_weights for multi-classes here***?

**In other words, I want to compute the class weight correctly in my case and makes there sum equal to 1. The class weights should should down-weight the loss for the majority classes and up-weight the loss for the minority classes...**

**Note::::**

I used the fully connected layer of deep learning for classification instead of SVM.

Answer (score 0):

```
weights = tf.gather(1. / class_weights, labels)
loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(
    logits=logits, labels=labels, weights=weights)
```